# IE8 history autofill sits in random place

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The history auto fill sits on a random place on IE8.
While the same works fine on IE9, IE10, firefox and chrome.

here is a snapshot of the issue.

[image]

I have been searching for this from a long time.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest right clicking the item, inspecting the element in your dev tools, finding what the id is of that autofill dropdown. See if there is some css attatched to that item. and then if necessary add some sort of CSS hack. below is a link to some tricks to target IE specifically. IE often requires little style hacks unfortunately. Hopefully the more they implement html5 standards the better this will become.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: I am already using a stylesheet for ie8 for the hacks. As soon as we try to inspect the history box it disappears. Infact it disappears with one away click that we do to inspect.

Comment: is it possibly still there in the DOM, just hidden, or is it truly being created / destroyed, if so then it's being created via javascript / javascript library and from there you could maybe track it down in the script and see what styles are being applied, if any.

Comment: its being created and destroyed. Unable to track its existence.

Comment: any way you could make this example public. There has to be some css that is being applied somewhere that is overriding the default style.